# Change a child class element's HTML using jQuery based off parent ID?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the HTML of a div element, to simple renumber the rows.
I cannot seem to grab the child element that has a `class="Col1"` value.
How can it be done correctly using jQuery?

```
function reorderTimeRowDisplayNumbers() {
    var elementsDisplayVisible = $(".schedTable").filter(':visible');
    if (elementsDisplayVisible.length > 0) {

        for (i = 1; i <= elementsDisplayVisible.length; i++) {

            var elementDisplayVisibleID = elementsDisplayVisible[i - 1].id;
            var myInt = parseInt(elementDisplayVisibleID.match(/[0-9]+/)[0], 10);

            alert(myInt);

            // update child div innerHTML
            if (myInt != i) {
                var divEl = document.getElementById(elementDisplayVisibleID);
                alert(divEl);
                $('#' + divEl + ' > .Col1').html(i -1);                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Final jQuery solution:

```
function reorderTimeRowDisplayNumbers() {
    // Renumber Display Number only. Called when adding or removing rows.
    $('.schedTable:visible').each(function (index) {
        if (Number(this.id.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) !== (index)) {
            $(this).children('.col1').html(index + 1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `divEl` is not hot the ID here, `elementDisplayVisibileID` is.
`$('#' + elementDisplayVisibileID + ' > .Col1').html(i -1);`

Comment: You sure love typing don't you. If you try really hard, you can make those variable names a little longer, and use more plain JS to make it take up a little more space.

Comment: @adeneo: Oomph. I could feel dat sass from here. ;)

Comment: It looks something like this with jQuery -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6LUTL/2/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to convert a **DOM element** to a **string** and use it in a selector. That won't work. You can use [one of the many traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) jQuery offers:

```
$(divEl).children('.Col1')
```

And here is a more succinct version of your code:

```
function reorderTimeRowDisplayNumbers() {
    $('.schedTable:visible').each(function(index) {
        if (Number(this.id.match(/[0-9]+/)[0]) !== (index + 1)) {
            $(this).children('.Col1').html(index);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For clarity to the OP, "you are trying to convert a DOM element to a string": `'#' + divEl + ' > .Col1'`

Comment: or `$('#' + divEl.id + ' > .Col1').html(i -1);`

Comment: @FelixKling thanks! but it breaks.. so if there was supposed to be Rows 1, 3, 4, 5 it only shows row 1 AND I can no longer add new rows. Bizarre.

Comment: @FelixKling found the cause.. the class name is case sensitive `col1`

Comment: One question: Where is index coming from? `function(index)`

Comment: I see.. it is part of the jQuery `.each()` function. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the **ID** you need plugin in there. You actually meant to write:

```
$('#' + elementDisplayVisibleID + ' > .Col1')
```